# Icon displays only near the item in first line of listView (View.Details)

Tags: c#

I wanna create a Task Manager application to kill, find proccesses and so on. Now i want to add some code to show process' icon near it's name (in all processes). I tried to make icons near the process name and it worked, but when application founds a new process, it replaces process' icon. And other processes haven't an icon. How to fix this? My code:

```
public void RefreshProcesses()
    {
        listView1.Items.Clear();
        double memsize = 0;
        int y = 0;
        foreach (Process p in processes)
        {
            
            try
            {
                memsize = 0;

                PerformanceCounter pc = new PerformanceCounter();
                pc.CategoryName = "Process";
                pc.CounterName = "Working Set - Private";
                pc.InstanceName = p.ProcessName;
                int PID = p.Id;
                memsize = (double)pc.NextValue() / (1000 * 1000);

                string desc = p.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileDescription;
                string version = p.MainModule.FileVersionInfo.FileVersion;
                string owner = GetProcessOwner(PID);
                string crtime = p.StartTime.ToString();
                string[] row = new string[] {p.ProcessName.ToString(), PID.ToString(), Math.Round(memsize, 1).ToString() + " MB", owner, desc, version, crtime };

                ImageList imageListSmall = new ImageList();
                Icon ico = Icon.ExtractAssociatedIcon(p.MainModule.FileName);
                imageListSmall.Images.Add(ico);
                ListViewItem itt = new ListViewItem(row, y);

                listView1.Items.AddRange(new ListViewItem[] { itt });

                listView1.SmallImageList = imageListSmall;
                pc.Close();
                pc.Dispose();
            }
            catch
            {
                richTextBox1.Text = richTextBox1.Text + "\rError";
            }
            y++;
        }
    }
```